# APT (Annotation Processing Tool)

Tags: java, annotations, apt

I was trying to find simple example to understand the usage of apt command, but I couldn't find a helpful resource for this.

I have referred this [Getting Started with the Annotation Processing Tool](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html)  but I do get a high level understanding. Moreover I want to write a code to test apt command. Can somebody post a simple example or better link to refer?

Comment: You can try to research source code of Jackdaw: https://github.com/vbauer/jackdaw

Answer (score 8):

Here's an example of creating a `Note` annotation and associated processor:

[APT: Compile-Time Annotation Processing with Java](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17876.html)

*Update. As of Java 1.7:*

> JSR 269, also known as the Language Model API, has two basic pieces: an API that models the Java programming language, and an API for writing annotation processors. This functionality is accessed through new options to the javac command; by including JSR 269 support, javac now acts analogously to the apt command in JDK 5.

Answer (score 6):

The book "Core Java 2: Advanced features" has a section called
[The apt Tool for Source-Level Annotation Processing](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/0131118269/annotations/ch13lev1sec5) which might help you.

*Update. As of Java 1.7:*

> JSR 269, also known as the Language Model API, has two basic pieces: an API that models the Java programming language, and an API for writing annotation processors. This functionality is accessed through new options to the javac command; by including JSR 269 support, javac now acts analogously to the apt command in JDK 5.