# Implementing Spring-like package scanning in Android

Tags: java, android, spring, reflection, dalvik

I'm attempting to implement a package-scanning feature, similar to Spring's `component-scan`, for the Android framework I'm developing. Basically, I would like to be able to specify a base package, e.g. `com.foo.bar` and retrieve all `Class` instances that have a particular annotation. I don't want to have to register every component with my framework as that would defeat the purpose of the auto scanning.

Based on my research, it seems that it's not possible with Java to retrieve resources given a package name using reflection. However, I briefly looked into the [Reflections framework](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/), and I'm wondering if there is an Android-compatible equivalent. If not, perhaps there is a slightly less obvious way to accomplish what I want to do.

I looked into the Spring source a bit to see how they achieved this, but I don't think what they are doing would work within the Dalvik runtime.

**Update**

Currently, the below code has been the best I can do to retrieve all classes that contain a specific annotation, but frankly it's a pretty poor solution. It makes some really unsafe assumptions about the `ClassLoader` plus it scans (and loads) all application classes.

```
public Set<Class<?>> getClassesWithAnnotation(Class<? extends Annotation> annotation) {
    Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    Field dexField = PathClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("mDexs");
    dexField.setAccessible(true);
    PathClassLoader classLoader = (PathClassLoader) Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    DexFile[] dexs = (DexFile[]) dexField.get(classLoader);
    for (DexFile dex : dexs) {
        Enumeration<String> entries = dex.entries();
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            String entry = entries.nextElement();
            Class<?> entryClass = dex.loadClass(entry, classLoader);
            if (entryClass != null && entryClass.isAnnotationPresent(annotation)) {
                classes.add(entryClass);
            }
        }
    }
    return classes;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I share the opinion of Joop Eggen and find his approach a good one. In Android I try to avoid the usual web app features which lead to a long lasting application start. I do not use reflection or package scanning.

But if you want to .... if I understand it correctly you want to have an annotation for a class. Instead of using annotations you could also use marker interfaces (to just have more possibilites).

### 1) Look at

- Annotation: [Java custom annotation and dynamic loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105842/java-custom-annotation-and-dynamic-loading)
  **Has an implementation in the question which just answers your question.**
- Annotation: [Scanning Java annotations at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime)
- Interface: [Find Java classes implementing an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435890/find-java-classes-implementing-an-interface)
- Interface: [Is something similar to ServiceLoader in Java 1.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251336/is-something-similar-to-serviceloader-in-java-1-5)
- Interface: [How can I get a list of all the implementations of an interface programmatically in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347248/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-implementations-of-an-interface-programmatically)
- Interface: Since the approach is  expensive, maybe the [ServiceLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) is a compromise between execution time and comfort, since it loads only the classes given in the services file. On the other hand if only classes with a certain interface are in your package then the ServiceLoader isn't that faster.

### 2) AndroidAnnotations

I would prefer the way [AndroidAnnotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki) work (maybe an integration in AndroidAnnotations is the preferable way): It automatically adds an extra compilation step that generates source code, using the standard Java Annotation Processing Tool. So instead of runtime scanning you execute code based on the annotations generated during compile time.

I think the Bean/EBean annotation could work for you (only single class): https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Enhance%20custom%20classes

A scan-feature is not available, see this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/androidannotations/fH1ary2ly3E)

### 3) Writing your own annotation processor

- See [APT (Annotation Processing Tool)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032629/aptannotation-processing-tool). The idea would be to generate a static function which returns a list of classes which are annotated, so that no class scanning is needed.
- A very good ressource is http://javadude.com/articles/annotations/index.html

Comment: Admittedly I'm not very familiar with how compilation-time source code generation works. I will have to take a look at how AndroidAnnotations does it, but I fear switching my framework to compile-time code generation would be a lot of work, although the reduction of performance overhead would be nice.

Comment: And did the first link help you?

Comment: [ClassIndex library](https://github.com/atteo/classindex) implements 3rd point and I can confirm it works with Android.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to find all the subclass at runtime.
So I've been looking for android class scanning.
This is my final code from what I gathered in web.
You will get the idea.

```
public static void findSubClasses(Context context, Class parent) {
    ApplicationInfo ai = context.getApplicationInfo();
    String classPath = ai.sourceDir;
    DexFile dex = null;
    try {
        dex = new DexFile(classPath);
        Enumeration<String> apkClassNames = dex.entries();
        while (apkClassNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String className = apkClassNames.nextElement();
            try {
                Class c = context.getClassLoader().loadClass(className);
                if (parent.isAssignableFrom(c)) {
                    android.util.Log.i("nora", className);
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //              android.util.Log.i("nora", className);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            dex.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:***

I found [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10076) in the Android issue tracker.  It appears that `ClassLoader.getResource(String)` is 'working as expected', in that it returns `null`.  This is expected because the DalvikVM does not keep the resources around after compiling.  There are workarounds listed in the issue, but there may be another way to access the classes you desire.

Use the [`PackageManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) to get a hold of an instance of [`ApplicationInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html).  `ApplicationInfo` has a public field called [`sourceDir`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#sourceDir) which is the full path (a `String`) to the location of the source directory for that application.  Create a `File` from this `String`, and you should be able to navigate to your package within the source directory.  Once there, you can use the method from my original answer to find the classes you are looking for.

```
String applicationSourceDir = 
    getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(androidPackageName, 0).sourceDir;
```

***/EDIT***

You should be able to use the [`ClassLoader.getResource(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) to get a `URL` to your specific package (the passed in `String` being the package name you are interested in delimited by path separators rather than periods).  With this `URL` you can then call [`getFile()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#getFile%28%29), from which you can create a Java `File` to the package folder.  Call [`packageFile.listFiles()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) from there, and you have your classes/subpackages.

Be recursive with the subpackages, and with the classes find the `Class` object using the static [`Class.forName(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Comment: Are you sure you can access the dex files like this? `ClassLoader.getResource('com/foo')` is returning `null` and based on some quick searching this seems like something that isn't actually possible. Otherwise it would be an excellent solution.

Comment: This is an exclusively native approach I have used to do this in a Java application.  I assumed that it would work in Android, due to there being no dependency on external libraries.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately in Android the classes are compiled into a `classes.dex` file, so it looks like this isn't an option. I had high hope for it too!

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work either since the "source directory" is actually just the APK. It still seems like my best option is to load the APK as a `DexFile` and iterate over all of its class entries like I described in the updated question. It works, but I don't like it and it's rather slow.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Vogar's [ClassPathScanner](https://code.google.com/p/vogar/source/browse/trunk/src/vogar/target/ClassPathScanner.java). It uses it to find test cases on the class path.

Comment: Thanks, Jesse. This appears to be a really good solution, but it seems that the `java.class.path` system property just returns `.`, so I'm unable to create a dex file from that. What am I not getting?

Answer (score 0):

In your java build process incorporate the class path scanning, generating injection data/code. This could then be ported too to Dalvik. It is even more efficient that dynamic scanning.